# Doctrine 2: how do you use a subquery column (in the SELECT clause)

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do a simple select query with a subquery in the SELECT clause and have simply not found a way to do it. I've tried with both DQL and with the QueryBuilder, neither work. The code follows, please don't say I could just use a join, this is a simplified example just to illustrate the problem, I have legitimate use cases for subqueries.

```
// With QueryBuilder
$query = $qb->select(array('a', 
                           '(SELECT at.addresstypeName 
                               FROM e:Addresstype at 
                              WHERE at.addresstypeId = a.addresstypeId
                            ) AS addresstypeName'))
            ->from('e:Address', 'a')
            ->where('a.addressId = :addressId')
            ->setParameter('addressId', 1);

// With DQL
$dql = "SELECT a, 
               (SELECT at.addresstypeName 
                  FROM e:Addresstype at 
                 WHERE at.addresstypeId = a.addresstypeId
               ) AS addresstypeName 
          FROM e:Address a 
         WHERE a.addressId = :addressId";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter(':addressId', 1);
```

The following relationship is defined on the Address table:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Addresstype")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="addresstype_id", referencedColumnName="addresstype_id")
 * })
 */
protected $addresstype;
```

In native SQL, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    (
        SELECT at.addresstype_name
        FROM addresstype at
        WHERE at.addresstype_id = a.addresstype_id
    ) AS addresstype_name
FROM address a
WHERE a.address_id = 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33):

```php
$query = $qb->select('a')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT at.addresstypeName
            FROM e:Addresstype at
            WHERE at.addresstypeId = a.addresstypeId) AS addresstypeName'
        )
    ->from('e:Address', 'a')
    ->where('a.addressId = :addressId')
    ->setParameter('addressId', 1);
```

Comment: Just tried it, I get the following error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 112 near 'addresstypeId)': Error: Class NP\entities\Address has no field or association named addresstypeId   Makes sense since the addresstypeId never gets defined on the Address entity, only the relationship, so you usually never have to use foreign keys.

Comment: I just copy paste your subquery to answer your question. I can not fix this subquery with no information about your entities (and schema). It's best if you post the real query with the real schema eitherway. Your question "how to use a subquery column" has been answered, please accept. I will try to assist you writing a good subquery (this is another question).

Comment: I added the details of the schema. I guess it would have been worth mentioning there was a relationship in there.

Comment: Forgot to say, I did upvote your answer. I'll wait to see if I can get an answer that actually makes the query work. If there isn't one, or if it's just not possible, I'll accept your answer as the right one.

Comment: Do you know how to write the query you want in native SQL? If you have trouble with your SQL then i will try to help you in a new question. The additional info you posted was too brief to be constructive.

Comment: Sure, just added the query in native SQL.

Answer (score 15):

For me subquery with doctrine works with this query :

```
$qb->select('e.field')
   ->addSelect('(SELECT count(mv.nm)
                FROM Clt\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\MV mv
                LEFT JOIN Clt\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\M ma WITH  mv.nm=ma.nm
                WHERE mv.ne=e.ne and ma.nm is null
                ) AS nm'
   )
   ->from($this->_entityName, 'e')
   ->leftJoin('e.m', 'm')
   ->where($qb->expr()->eq('t.id'.$typeModule, $idElementModule));
```

Note that in the left join you must use WITH instead of ON...

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but if you want, you could have used another query builder as your subquery:

```
 $qb->select("a")
            ->addSelect("(" . $qb2->select("at.addresstypeName")
                ->from("e:Addresstype", "at")
                ->where("at.addresstypeId = a.addresstypeId")
                ->getDQL() . ") AS addresstypeName"
            )
            ->from('e:Address', 'a')
            ->where('a.addressId = :addressId')
            ->setParameter('addressId', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you! The sub query is more elegant in my opinion. This answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario what I needed was to look into a join and find an Id and use it as boolean, found 1 otherwise 0, then applying this to orderBy. DQL expressions worked only when combined with Where clause, which wasn't my case. So, a DQL subselect saved me.

Adapted more or less to your scenario, it would look like this:

```
// With QueryBuilder
// In AddressRepository
// Where one address may belong to several addressTypes

public function getWithType($addressType){

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a1');
$qb->addSelect('a1.someField', 'a1.otherField')
$qb->addSelect(
        '(SELECT at.addressTypeName 
        FROM App\Entity\Address a2
        JOIN a2.addressType at
        WHERE at.id = '.$addressType.' AND a2.id = a1.id
        ) AS addressTypeName')
//The rest part of the query
        
}
```