# Order by with many column

Tags: symfony

sorry for my english, i'm french,

In my project, I have entities Car, Boat, Bike and these entities are call in an entity Advert. The price is located in the entities Car, Boat and Bike so for order by price, I need to merge Car.price, boat.price and bike.price in one column in my query.
I have test :

```
$query->addSelect('CONCAT(c.priceTtc, b.priceTtc, bo.priceTtc, t.priceTtc, p.priceTtc) AS all_price');
$query->orderBy('all_price', $order);
```

but my result not return my entity advert but it return an array with advert in key 0 and NULL in a key "all_price"

Do you have a solution to "order by" my result by price ?

I have the same problem for "order by" adverts by "registration_date" of the vehicle

Comment: merge not merde :).

Comment: That's perfectly normal since Doctrine cannot set 'price_all' in your advert entity, it adds it in an array. What do you want ? You didn't say it in your question. Explain us how you want it returned. Where should go the all_price result if you become just an advert entity as expected ?

Comment: Thanks for your return, I have change my post.

Comment: I need to "order by" my result (list of adverts) by car.price, boat.price, ... like I was "order by advert.price" except that the price is stored in entity car, boat,...

Comment: OK you just want it ordered by all_price but don't want all_price to be returned ?

Comment: yes if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you need is "Union" instead of "Concat". "Concat" basically merges values of different columns in one row which doesn't help much in your case but Union merges results of different queries together and you can sort them together, however using union with doctrine could be a little tricky and it you need to use [Native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

Maybe it is easiest solution is to use sub-query to make query on results of other queries. here are some examples:

[Doctrine 2: how do you use a subquery column (in the SELECT clause)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162841/doctrine-2-how-do-you-use-a-subquery-column-in-the-select-clause)
http://melikedev.com/2013/06/07/php-doctrine-dql-select-subquery/

your other option (best practice in my opinion) is to change your entity structure and use [doctrine inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) (probably **single table** or  **Class Table** but not  **Mapped Superclasses**). For example make a Vehicle entity as parent class of Boat, Bike, Car and put all common properties (such as price) in it and query Vehicle directly and get all the results together(with sort and everything).

Other alternative solution (not recommended) is to merge and sort results of different queries from different entities(Car, Boat, Bike) in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use CONCAT and to retrieve only the advert entity.
You can not do a subquery with doctrine.

But I propose to ORDER directly on each fields :

```
->orderBy('c.priceTtc',$order)
->addOrderBy('b.priceTtc',$order)
->addOrderBy('bo.priceTtc',$order)
->addOrderBy('t.priceTtc',$order)
->addOrderBy('p.priceTtc',$order)
```

The result should be the same.