# Doctrine - sub-select in From

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Using Symfony version 3.0.9 I have an sql query that I've converted to dql as follows:

original query SQL:

```
SELECT
        Product_Name,
        Product_Code,
        sum(quantity)AS quantity
    FROM
        ldr
    GROUP BY
        Product_Code,
        Product_Name
```

original query using Doctrine:

```
$query->select ( 'o.productName, o.productCode, sum(o.quantity) as quantity ' );
$query->from ( 'BillingBundle:Ldr', 'o' );
$query->add ( 'groupBy', 'o.productName, o.productCode');
```

This works fine and gives me a list of all Products and the Quantities.

Now I want to do a Sub-select in the From clause, in order to combine all the Products whose Quantities are less than 1% into an "Other" segment.

The SQL for this is straightforward:

```
SELECT
    case when quantity > (total * 0.01 ) then Product_Name else 'Other' end as name,
    case when quantity > (total * 0.01 ) then Product_Code else 'Other' end as code,
    sum(quantity)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Product_Name,
            Product_Code,
            sum(quantity)AS quantity,
            (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM ldr)AS total
        FROM
            ldr
        GROUP BY
            Product_Code,
            Product_Name
    )AS segments
GROUP BY
    code,
    name
```

However I'm having trouble expressing the Sub-select in the From clause in Doctrine.
My DQL (attempt) is:

```
    $query->select ( 'case when sum(o.quantity) > (o.total * 0.01 ) then o.productName else :other end as name,  
            case when sum(o.quantity) > (o.total * 0.01 ) then o.productCode else :other end as code,
            sum(o.quantity) as quantity ' );
    $query->from ( ' (SELECT
            l.Product_Name,
            l.Product_Code,
            sum(l.quantity)AS quantity,
            (SELECT sum(ld.quantity) FROM BillingBundle:Ldr ld) AS total
        FROM
            BillingBundle:Ldr l
        GROUP BY
            l.Product_Code,
            l.Product_Name )', 'o' );
    $query->add ( 'groupBy', 'name, code');

    $query->setParameter ( 'other', "Other" );
```

but I get an error

> Error: Class '(' is not defined.

What is the correct way to express the sub-select in From?
Do I need to use some RawSql approach?

I can't use `addSelect()` because the subselect is in the From clause

Comment: You should check out addSelect() as answered in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/18164553/3986395

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2: how do you use a subquery column (in the SELECT clause)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162841/doctrine-2-how-do-you-use-a-subquery-column-in-the-select-clause)

Comment: this is not a duplicate - in my case the subselect is in the FROM clause, so `addSelect()` won't work.

Comment: This sounds like a job for raw SQL

Comment: @JasonRoman it seems you're probably right.  How annoying!

Comment: You should be doing this stuff in your application code, I will tell you how, First get total  sum from your entity via separate query then fetch product name, code and quantity like in inner query as a separate query from entity, while show the results you can add condition in your loop by comparing product quantity with total and show product name or other

Comment: when you say 'should' be doing this in Application code do you really mean 'should', as in: it's considered best-practice, or do you mean 'must' because Doctrine only seems to support basic SQL structures?  As a developer it seems very poor practice to write loops in my Application code where a SQL statement can do the job.